# Why is it necessary to block a signal before sigwait()'ing it?

Tags: signals, real-time

In APUE, chapter 12 page 454, it is mentioned that:

> To avoid erroneous behavior, a thread must block the signals it is waiting for ...

The similar is said in the standard:

> The signals defined by *set* shall have been blocked at the time of the call to *sigwait()*; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

What erroneous/undefined behavior is being discussed in these texts? I can't find a rationale or application usage in the standard, and I'm having difficulty comprehending the explanation in the book:

> if the signals are not blocked ..., then a timing window is opened up where one of the signals can be delivered to the thread before it completes its call to `sigwait`.

Comment: In short: because `sigwait` is a different mechanism of handling signals than `signal` and `sigaction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer first takes the readers to the historical perspective of standard development, then it brings the attention of the readers to specific texts of the standard to explain the reason for the requirement.

In XPG Issue 3, `sigaction`, along with `sig*set`, `sigismember`, `sigpending`, `sigprocmask`, and `sigsuspend`, are introduced for alignment with POSIX.1-1988 standard. Of these, `sigaction` provided the most comprehensive and consistent interface for specifying signal dispositions; `sigpending`, `sigprocmask` and `sigsuspend` provided ways for fine-grained response to signals.

In XPG Issue 4 (the oldest currently available in digital form), `sigaltstack`, `sig{hold,ignore,pause,relse,set}`, `siginterrupt` were introduced. The latest standard didn't say where they were from, only that all but `sigaltstack` are obsolescent, as they only work in single-threaded processes.

In XPG Issue 5, which is Single Unix Specification Version 2, `pthread_sigmask`, `sigqueue`, `sigtimedwait`, `sigwaitinfo`, and `sigwait` are introduced for alignment with POSIX realtime and threads extensions.

Now, it's important to look at 2 other places in the standard.

1st in General Information for the System Interfaces volume, Signal Concepts:

> ... a signal can be "blocked" from delivery to a thread. If the action associated with a blocked signal is anything other than to ignore the signal, and if that signal is generated for the thread, the signal shall remain pending until it is unblocked, it is accepted when it is selected and returned by a call to the `sigwait()` function, or the action associated with it is set to ignore the signal.

Obviously, apart from possibly eventually ignoring the signal, the signal can have 2 ways of reaching the process/thread - being unblocked, or being accepted by `sigwait` (and its siblings such as `sigtimedwait` and `sigwaitinfo`)

2nd in `sigaction`:

> The result of the use of sigaction() and a sigwait() function concurrently within a process on the same signal is unspecified.

Obviously, `sigwait` had been envised as a secondary method of processing signals.

That is further confirmed by the following text in the rationale for the `sigtimedwait` and `sigwaitinfo` interface:

> The sigwait functions provide a synchronous mechanism for threads to wait for asynchronously-generated signals.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the [qnx documentation](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/s/sigwait.html), but it's relevant for all Unix and Unix like distributions:

> The signals defined by set should be blocked before you call
> sigwait(). If you don't block them, there's a race condition in that a
> signal can be delivered just before the call is made, causing the call
> to block, which you might not want it to do.

Comment: The roughly-same is said in APUE which I quoted in my question. I'd appreciate an analysis of code flow in which `sigwait` and `pthread_sigmask` involved if it can be provided.