# sigtimedwait sets errno to ETIMEDOUT with timeout=0

Tags: linux, embedded, signals, timeout, multithreading

In a cpp multithreaded program, we're using a copy of Linux `sigwait` implementation at the end of our main function, after creating all threads and initializing our program:

```
   sigset_t  mask;
   struct sigaction sa;
   signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

   sigemptyset(&mask);
   sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
   
   sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_NODEFER;
   sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
   sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

   // Copy/paste of sigwait source code 
   // but keeping full siginfo (instead of just returning signo)
   // and adding ETIMEDOUT as a do/while continue condition
   siginfo_t si = {};
   int ret = 0;
   do
   {
      ret = sigtimedwait (&mask, &si, 0);      
      if(ret == -1)
      {
         if(errno == ETIMEDOUT)
         {
            printf("sigtimedwait timeout\n");
         }
      }
   }
   while (ret < 0 && (errno == EINTR || errno == ETIMEDOUT));
```

`sigwait` implementation for reference:

```
int
__sigwait (const sigset_t *set, int *sig)
{
  siginfo_t si;
  int ret;
  do
    ret = __sigtimedwait (set, &si, 0);
  /* Applications do not expect sigwait to return with EINTR, and the
     error code is not specified by POSIX.  */
  while (ret < 0 && errno == EINTR);
  if (ret < 0)
    return errno;
  *sig = si.si_signo;
  return 0;
}
```

`sigtimedwait` declaration for reference:

```
int sigtimedwait(const sigset_t *restrict set, 
                 siginfo_t *restrict info, 
                 const struct timespec *restrict timeout);
```

`sigtimedwait` sets `errno` to `ETIMEDOUT` when our program is running under high load, i.e., process uses >50% CPU, almost all available memory is cached for sdcard write operations.

This is not always repeatable and happens randomly once or several times throughout our high load sequence lasting up to 3 minutes. This does not occur during regular ops.

We're running Linux 4.14 on an armv7l.

Our sigaction `handler` does not get called, even after adding all possible signals to sigaddset and sigaction. Looking at `siginfo_t si`, all values are unset - reading zeroes.

I can't find any mention of `sigtimedwait` returning `ETIMEDOUT` in Linux manuals.

Does anyone know what might be causing that?

Comment: Do you have `SIGINT` "blocked" - in all threads? Have a read of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685617/why-is-it-necessary-to-block-a-signal-before-sigwaiting-it) ...

Comment: Thanks for the thread. Yes, we call sigemptyset(&mask) sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT) and pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) before each pthread_create

Comment: OK, so the mask is inherited ... see the man page on [sigtimedwait()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigtimedwait) - firstly, be pedantic and only look at `errno` if it returns `-1`; secondly, read the notes about passing `NULL` (aka 0) for the `timeout` argument of `sigtimedwait()` - this man page equates this to `sigwaitinfo()` which is blocking (check your kernel/libc versions) - to poll you need to pass a `timespec` struct with 0 in each value; thirdly, work out what `ETIMEDOUT` actually means to your code and handle it properly - this doesn't seem like a reason to terminate your signal loop.

Comment: I ran a test and `ETIMEDOUT` always gets set with `sigtimedwait()` returning -1. Passing a `timespec` with {} only returns `EAGAIN` since there are no pending signal at our program init (see man page). My intent was to use `sigwait`. Since `sigwait` returns `ETIMEDOUT` without any explanation, I ended up copying `sigwait` source code and added `ETIMEDOUT` to the errnos to ignore. The program runs fine when `ETIMEDOUT` gets set. But why does `ETIMEDOUT` gets set, and does it indicate a larger underlying problem - that's what puzzles me.

Comment: Sorry, you're just confusing me now - firstly, like I said, be pedantic even if you think it will always return -1 ... actually test that you get -1 before looking at `errno`. Secondly, `errno` is thread safe, but only if you have correctly built for threads e.g. `-pthread`, `-lpthread`, and maybe even `-D_REENTRANT` - if you haven't built correctly then you might be looking at a global `errno` which might be changed by another thread (?) ... the fact that `sigwait()` is returning `ETIMEDOUT` should be making you wary, since this should never happen - the correct `errno` is `EAGAIN`.

Comment: See updated code: I added an if `ret == -1` before checking `errno`, and I get the same results. I do compile with `-pthread` (which is equivalent to `-lpthread -D_REENTRANT`). I even verified that `int *errno_p = __errno_location();` is different in each thread I create. I tried setting a watchpoint on our main thread `errno` address but gdb crashes once the watchpoint is set. Any idea how to verify that errno is not set by another thread? Could it be from shared library?

Comment: Check that all library calls you make are marked as thread safe? After that, I'm out of ideas ...